# Python: Loop through list but repeat some of the items

Tags: python, scripting

In Python, I am writing a script that will simulate a customer placing an order. It will consist of creating the order, adding lines to it, and then checking out. I am currently doing it with something like:

```
api = ['login', 'createOrder', 'scanBarCode', 'addLine', 'checkout']
for apiName in apiList:
  #call API
```

I am designing this more as a framework so it would be easy to add new APIs in case things change. My design question is this: How can I code it so that I can call scanBarCode and addLine N number of times? Something like:

```
api = ['login', 'createOrder', 'scanBarCode', 'addLine', 'checkout']
numberOfLines = (random number)
for apiName in apiList:
  #call API
  #if API name is scanBarCode, repeat this and the next API numberOfLines times, then continue with the rest of the flow
```

Comment: What do you mean by *call* 'scanBarCode' etc? Are these functions? They look like they're strings here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should get you started:

```
import random
api = ['login', 'createOrder', 'scanBarCode', 'addLine', 'checkout']
numberOfLines = random.randint(1, 10)   # replace 10 with your desired maximum
for apiName in api:
    if apiName == 'scanBarCode':
        for i in range(numberOfLines):
            # call API and addLine
    else:
        # call API
```

Answer (score 1):

With a loop using range  or (preferably) xrange:

```
if apiName == 'scanBarCode':
    for _ in xrange(numberOfLines):
        {{ do stuff }}
```

Comment: ``xrange()`` only needed in 2.x, of course. In 3.x, ``range()`` returns an iterable.